Why cant we use $d(a^x)/dx = a^x \ln x$ to differentiate $y = 1^x$?
Why cant we use d(a^x)/dx = a^x ln x to differentiate y = 1^x ? Is there any other way to differentiate it ?

$1^x$ is a constant function, Which means its derivative is $0$, Though, even using your method, $\ln 1=0$ too, because it is $a^x \ln a$ not $a^x \ln x$

You have a mistake. The correct formula is $$\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \cdot \ln{a}.$$
So $$\frac{d}{dx} 1^x = 1^x \cdot \ln{1}=0$$
